# Restrict user to upload a certain type on Azure

Tags: azure, file-upload, blob, image-uploading

I am developing a web app, and I want to restrict the user to upload a certain type on the Azure blob for e.g. only images or PDFs only.

Is there a way that when I press the upload Image, it checks whether it is an image or not? If it is not an image it rejects the Request? Better to have the validation at server side

This is the coding I am using:

```
<div>
    Select Image to upload a ClassDiagram
    <input name="classdiagram" type="file" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" />
</div>
```

**Partial Code of public ActionResult ImageUpload()**

```
var dfd = Request.Files["dfd"];
var classdiagram = Request.Files["classdiagram"];
// Code hidden for Brevity. Multiple var instances.    

// --- SETTING UP THE CONTAINER --- //

// Create the CloudStorageAccount

StorageCredentials credentials = new StorageCredentials("swiftdevelopmentstorage", "HqaCkZjdQ8w/DX/fS3wDxU6HXbeqV5EZ1b+UQaKALxaJDrN9JoZZYn8Q0KT6QR4tCrdGQicxE+tKRKScjINW8w==");
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credentials, true);


CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

// Retrieve Reference to container
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("systemdesign");

// Create if nonexistent
container.CreateIfNotExists();

// Change Default Private Permission to Public
container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob });


// Depending on the Design type (e.g. Flowchart, dfd..) the blob will be uploaded to a different sub folder

if (dfd != null)
{
    string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("dfd/image_{0}{1}",
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Path.GetExtension(dfd.FileName));
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);

// Rest of the code is all other if cases for the remaining Request.Files
```

The problem is that the `accept="image/*"`, still doesn't deny uploading of other extensions if the users switches to "Show All"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that the accept="image/*", still doesn't deny uploading
>   of other extensions if the users switches to "Show All"

You're correct. This way, you will not be able to prevent users from uploading any files.

There are few things you could do:

- **Check content-type of uploaded content**: One way you could do it is by checking the content type of uploaded content. For images, it would be `image/*` (e.g. `image/png`, `image/gif` etc.) and filter requests based on that. However again this is not fool-proof way of doing things. What if somebody renames an `exe` file as `png` and uploads it.
- **Reading the file type from file headers**: If I am not mistaken, each file's type information is stored in file headers. What you could do is read the file contents and identify its type by reading the file header and identify if the file type is an acceptable file type. You may find this link useful for that: http://www.exnol.com/how-to-open-unknown-files-without-extension.

Comment: Thanks for the link. For my web app I think just checking the content-type of the uploaded content would be enough. Will that Filtering be applied in my Controller? (Since I am using an MVC) or in the Form itself?